# Как декодировать сжатую строку из PHP в Swift?

Tags: php, ios, swift

У меня есть текстовый файл сжатый с помощью функции zlib в php:

```
base64_encode(gzcompress('привет')) // "eJy7sP9iw4UdFzZd2HqxCQA6EAjD"
```

Теперь мне нужно прочитать этот файл в iOS приложении.
Для этого я попытался использовать библиотеку https://github.com/mw99/DataCompression

```
let data = Data(base64Encoded: "eJy7sP9iw4UdFzZd2HqxCQA6EAjD")!
print(data.decompress(withAlgorithm: .zlib)) // nil
```

Но в консоле я получаю nil

Comment: Не вижу возможности у этого репозитория что вы описываете (base64Encoded), это только для декодирования строки. А где код для его распаковки?

Comment: Метод decompress во второй строке это и есть метод отсюда - https://github.com/mw99/DataCompression/blob/master/Sources/DataCompression/DataCompression.swift#L49

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы использовали не тот метод из данной библиотеки для распаковки. У вас данные в php упакованы с помощью алгоритма `zlib deflate` ([тыц](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.gzcompress.php)), который нужно распаковывать с помощью метода `unzip`

```
let data = Data(base64Encoded: "eJy7sP9iw4UdFzZd2HqxCQA6EAjD")!
let deсompressedData = data.unzip()!
let str = String(data: deсompressedData, encoding: .utf8)
print(str) // Optional("привет")
```